# Strange NullPointerException in Actors in scala using play framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework, parallel-processing, actor

I want to do some parallel computation and I'm getting a really strange java.lang.NullPointerException on calling ANY functions outside the object I have.

Take a look:

```
case class Return(session: String, job: Int)
case class Ready(n: Int)
case class DoJob(session: String, job: Int)
case class NotReady


object Notifications extends Controller with Secure {

  class AtorMeio extends Actor {
    import scala.collection.mutable.{Map => MMap}
    val job: MMap[(String, Int), Option[Int]] = MMap()

    def act {
      loop {
        react {
          case DoJob(session, jobn) =>
            if (job.get((session, jobn)).isEmpty) {
              jobn match {
                case 1 =>
                  job.put((session, jobn), None)

                    val n = Messaging.oi //Messaging.retrieveNumberOfMessages(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false))
                    job.put((session, jobn), Some(n))

                case 2 =>
                  // do!
              }
            }
          case Return(session, jobn) =>
            if (job.get((session, jobn)).isDefined && job.get((session, jobn)).get.isDefined) {
              val ret = job.get((session, jobn)).get.get
              job.remove((session, jobn))

              reply(Ready(ret))
            }
            else
              reply(NotReady)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private var meuator: AtorMeio = null
  lazy val ator = {
    if (Option(meuator).isEmpty) {
      meuator = new AtorMeio
      meuator.start
    }

    meuator
  }

  def pendingNotifications = {    
    ator ! DoJob(session.getId, 1)

    ator !? Return(session.getId, 1) match {
      case Ready(ret) =>
        if (ret.toString != Option[String](params.get("current")).getOrElse("-1")) "true" else Suspend("80s")
      case _ =>
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting an error in executing Messaging.oi which is basically an object with:

```
def oi = 4
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
controllers.Notifications$AtorMeio@1889d53: caught java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controllers.Messaging$.oi(Messaging.scala:108)
    at     controllers.Notifications$AtorMeio$$anonfun$act$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Notifications.scala:38)
at controllers.Notifications$AtorMeio$$anonfun$act$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Notifications.scala:31) at scala.actors.ReactorTask.run(ReactorTask.scala:34)
at scala.actors.ReactorTask.compute(ReactorTask.scala:66)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:147)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.quietlyExec(ForkJoinTask.java:422)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.mainLoop(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:340)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:325)
```

Line 108 is exactly this oneliner def. Ahh entrance point is def pendingNotifications.

Anyone can help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried replacing

```
 private var meuator: AtorMeio = null
```

by either:

```
private var meuator: AtorMeio = None
```

Comment: thx for the answer.. but why would that compile? and I don't access it directly.. I use a lazy val called ator for that.

Comment: What I wanted to say was to replace the null by a value of Option. It seems your error is related to that null in there. I know it's using a lazy val, but having a starting value of Null may not be the best idea .

Comment: changed it to private var meuator: Option[Actor] = None .. still not working =/ Any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Configure your breakpoints view in your debugger to halt/break on NullPointerExceptions ...

And: you did see you set this to null here:

```
  private var meuator: AtorMeio = null
```

?? Or?

Comment: please check: "lazy val ator" and I start from "def pendingNotifications"

Answer (score 0):

Ok people, after digging a lot I discovered the problem: Somehow, somewhere if you have the "Controller" class from play framework mixed in, it crashes mercifully. So I just wrapped this thing into a 'clean' class and it worked.